# Extending VBA code to delete characters for certain cells for entire workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am super new the VBA, but I've been working with it a lot the passed couple days. I have many workbooks with similar structure that have 50+ sheets. I keep getting stuck on not having my excel Macro extend to the entire workbook.

I need to delete characters from the left and right of two columns with string values. Here is the code:

```
Sub Trim()

Dim c As Range

 For Each c In Range("B5", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 c.Value = Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 10)
 c.Value = Right(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 7)

 Next c

 For Each c In Range("C5", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 c.Value = Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 16)

 Next c

End Sub
```

This does what I want it to do but for only my active workbook. I've tried several things to try to have it loop to all sheets but I haven't been successful.

I greatly appreciate the help thanks!

Comment: You mean *only for the active worksheet* :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested but it should be ok

```
 Sub MyTrim()
' avoid Trim because it is a built-in function!
Dim c As Range, wb As Worksheet

For Each wb In ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets
     For Each c In wb.Range("B5", wb.Range("B" & wb.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         c.Value = Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 10)
         c.Value = Right(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 7)
     Next c

     For Each c In wb.Range("C5", wb.Range("C" & wb.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         c.Value = Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 16)
     Next c
Next wb

End Sub
```

**EDIT** (based on the second comment below)

The above code (also the original posted) works only when the second argument of `Left` and `Right` is non-negative. If there is a negative argument, an error such as the one you described is raised. I am not sure what exactly you would like to extract, but most likely`Left` and `Right` are not doing what you would like them to do..

**Example:**

if `c.Value =  "a string somewhat long"` then

`Left(c.Value), Len(c.value)-10)="a string som"` and then

`Right(c.Value, Len(c.Value)-7) = "g som"`

The `Right` part acts on `"a string som"`.

You can actually stop the code just before it fails and check if it does what you want as follows:

above the line
`c.Value = Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 10)`
add the line 
`debug.Assert Len(c.Value) >= 10`

and above the line `c.Value = Right(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 7)`
add the line 
`debug.Assert Len(c.Value) >= 7`

You can think of this as an expression saying "make sure the length of the string is at least 10, and stop if this is not true. This will stop the code execution when it is not true. Then you can go to the Immediate Window (either Ctrl+G or View-> Immediate Window) and type `? c.Value` This will display the value of `c`. Finally, when the code stops, the line at which it stops is marked yellow. If you want to execute the following line of code, hit `F8`. Every time you hit `F8`, a single line of code will be executed.

As a final observation, if you change `c.Value = Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 10)` 
with

`c.Value = Left(c.Value, IIf(Len(c.Value) - 10 >= 0, Len(c.Value) - 10, 0))`

the code will not through an error.. But in the cases it would throw an error before, it will now eliminate the whole word (i.e., return an empty string). I am not sure though that this the desirable behavior.. but let me know! :)

Comment: Thanks, but - I actually tried this exact code and it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Are you calling a different workbook from the one where the subroutine is? Are you using wb everywhere (I.e., all Rows. Range, etc should be appended by .wb). What exactly happens? Does it give an error?

Comment: Didn't really notice my answer is identical. We are both reusing the same code from the OP. So it's hard to be NOT identical.

Anyways I've deleted my answer, if that makes you feel offended

Comment: Hey @sam092, no no no, by no means I got offended :) My point was that every answer has to add a piece of information that cannot be found at the existing answers. And of course I believe it was accidental, it is hard to give a different answer to that question anyway:)

Comment: @loannis - What happens when I use this is that it keeps looping around Column B and when it runs out of characters I get an error for "invalid argument". I know this because when i change the code to just taking away one character at a time I can clearly see this happening. I've been working a lot on this and can't fins the issue.

Comment: @Roxxy.32, I added a few more details on the answer. I believe the problem lies on the `Left` and `Right` part, and not on the worksheets issue.. I hope the amendment helps, let me know what you think!

Comment: Yup, exactly. That was the issue. Thank you got all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Excel really works better as a workbook tool with formulas.

At the risk of not exactly answering the question, what about creating a new workbook with formulas that extract the required information from the original workbooks. Then, by using a formula such as

```
=LEFT(INDIRECT("[Workbook]Sheet1!B1"), LEN(INDIRECT("[Workbook]Sheet1!B1"))-7)
```

where the entire formula reference can be computed in the string argument, you extract any cell, and then process it as required.

As a fully descriptive solution, although the performance may be similar to the VBA solution, it requires no knowledge of another language and is much easier to debug.